# bootstrap function "modal on shown" not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, php, function, bootstrap-modal

I can open my modal with script (id matches), but function on show does not get triggered. I just want to find out why can't I trigger that function? Is my js syntax wrong? Should I have it all in "document ready" function?.

**MAIN**

```
 <body>
<?php

    require 'connect.php';

    $r = $db->getReference('guests');
    $ref = $r->getChild($dat)->getChild($id);
    $value = $ref->getValue();
    $json = json_encode($value);

    require 'model.html';
?>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#modalas').modal('show');

    var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $json; ?>');
    console.log(obj);
    var vardass = obj.vardas;

    $("#modalas").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    console.log(vardass)
    var modal = $(this)
    $("#post_form")[0].reset();
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(vardass)

        document.getElementById("NameInput").value = obj.vardas;
        document.getElementById("LastInput").value = obj.pavarde;
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is called `show.bs.modal` not `shown.bs.modal`

From https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#js-events

> Bootstrap provides custom events for most plugins' unique actions.
>   Generally, these come in an infinitive and past participle form -
>   where the infinitive (ex. show) is triggered at the start of an event,
>   and its past participle form (ex. shown) is triggered on the
>   completion of an action.
>
> As of 3.0.0, all Bootstrap events are namespaced.
>
> All infinitive events provide preventDefault functionality. This
>   provides the ability to stop the execution of an action before it
>   starts.
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {   if (!data) return
> e.preventDefault() // stops modal from being shown })
> ```

Comment: @JuliusJ Well in your code you are showing your modal before adding the event listener. Swap it around

Comment: No, document ready makes sure your javascript is being called when the DOM is ready. So currently your code does this: `Wait for DOM` => `Show Modal (no event listener added yet)` => `Add Event Listener onShow to Modal`

Comment: @Xantev Yes!! You saved me :D It all makes sense now :)

Comment: @JuliusJ Cool. You can select the answer as `accepted answer` by ticking the green check mark next to the answer if it helped you, to help other users finding the question/answer.